# What's wrong with this Coder Byte code (easy challenge #2)?

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, replace

What the challenge asks:

Using the JavaScript language, have the function LetterChanges(str) take the str parameter being passed and modify it using the following algorithm. Replace every letter in the string with the letter following it in the alphabet (ie. c becomes d, z becomes a). Then capitalize every vowel in this new string (a, e, i, o, u) and finally return this modified string.

My solution:

```
function LetterChanges(str) { 

var alphabet = [a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,j,k,l,m,n,o,p,q,r,s,t,u,v,w,x,y,z];
var vowels = [a,e,i,o,u];
var stringToArray = str.split("");

for (i=0; i<=stringToArray.length; i++){       //goes through new array one-by-one
    var originalLetter = stringToArray[i]      // names each letter
    var alphabetPosition = alphabet.indexOf(); // finds letter position in alphabet array
    var newAlphabetPosition = alphabetPosition + 1; // adds one to that position
    var newLetter = alphabet[newAlphabetPosition];  // changes the old letter to the new
    newLetter = stringToArray[i];              // sends new letter to its position on new array
    if (newLetter.isInArray(vowels){           // finds if new letter is a vowel
        newLetter = newLetter.toUpperCase();   // if yes, turn into upper case
        }      
    str = stringToArray.toStr()                 //turns array back to string, and names it str
}
return str;         
}
```

I've tried to be very clear on my thinking, adding the steps one by one. Please refrain from using quick methods, since I really want to correctly understand the reasoning behind the challenge, and not memorize methods.

Comment: What's your actual question?  If this code works properly, and you have other questions about refactoring, performance, maintainability you can also consider [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/).  Do not cross post on both sites.

Comment: @Kvera This code [does not appear to work correcly](http://repl.it/languages/JavaScript)...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code doesn't work... because of a few errors:

1. What is i?  Did you forget to declare it?
2. Once you convert a string to an array... the first character starts at 0, and the last character is length -1.  Your for-loop conditional has i **<=** stringToArray.length which would include one character beyond the array length.
3. var alphabetPosition = alphabet.indexOf();  Index of what?  Did you forget indexOf(originalLetter)?
4. You forgot "z".  You need some logic to "wrap-around" back to "a".
5. isInArray isNotAFunctionYouShowedUs.  Actually Javascript only has "indexOf" which returns -1 on no-match... unless I'm mistaken.

```js
function LetterChanges(str) {
  for (var i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
    var newCharCode = str.charCodeAt(i) + 1; //Get Decimal Value for character at index "i", and increment by 1.
    if (newCharCode == 123)  {  //Pesky 'z' becomes '{'.  Lets change it to 'a' instead.
      newCharCode = 97; // 'a' = 97.
    }
    if ([97,101,105,111,117].indexOf(newCharCode)!=-1) {  //Is it a vowel?  (97 = a, 101 = e, 105 = i, 111= o, 117 = u)
      newCharCode-=32;  //Make it capital.  (65 = A, 69 = E, 73 = I, 79 = O, 85 = U)
    }
    console.log(newCharCode);
    str = str.substr(0,i) + String.fromCharCode(newCharCode) + str.substr(i+1); //Convert it back to a character, and stick it back into the string.
    console.log(str);
  }
  return str;
}
```

I marked up something kinda quick... just for fun.  (untested)  It only makes use of 2 variables and does some old fashioned ascii trickery.

Answer (score 0):

My CoderByte Solutions (https://github.com/ambatiramireddy/My-CoderByte-Solutions)

```
function LetterChanges(str) {
        var vowels = 'aeiou', result = '', changedChar;
        for (i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
            var c = str.charCodeAt(i);
            if (c >= 97 && c < 122)
                changedChar = String.fromCharCode(c + 1);
            else if (c == 122)
                changedChar = String.fromCharCode(97);
            else
                changedChar = str[i];

            if (vowels.indexOf(changedChar) != -1)
                changedChar = changedChar.toUpperCase();

            result += changedChar;
        }
        return result;
    }
```